# Retrieve values from `.properties` file | lateinit property has not been initialized

Tags: spring, spring-boot, properties, kotlin

I'm trying to create a spring boot application were my class will read from a file `src/main/resources/application.properties`. But for some reason I can't get my Kotlin to work with these values (returning a `lateinit property url has not been initialized`.

**src/main/resources/application.properties** (note, not explicitly called anywhere?)

```
spring.datasource.url=someUrl
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.postgresql.Driver
```

**Kotlin**

```
@Component
open class BaseDAO() {
     @Autowired
     lateinit var datasource: DataSource;
  }
```

**new error**

```
kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property datasource has not been initialized
    at quintor.rest.persistence.BaseDAO.getDatasource(BaseDAO.kt:18) ~[classes/:na]
    at quintor.rest.persistence.EventDAO.getMultipleEvents(EventDAO.kt:45) ~[classes/:na]
    at quintor.rest.persistence.EventDAO.getComingOpenEvents(EventDAO.kt:98) ~[classes/:na]
    at quintor.rest.persistence.EventService.getComingEvents(EventService.kt:23) ~[classes/:na]
    at quintor.rest.spring.EventsController.getEvents(EventsController.kt:37) ~[classes/
```

**Application**

```
@SpringBootApplication
open class Application : SpringBootServletInitializer(){
    companion object {
        @JvmStatic fun main(args: Array<String>) {
            SpringApplication.run(Application::class.java, *args);
        }
        @Override
        protected  fun configure(app:SpringApplicationBuilder):SpringApplicationBuilder{
            return app.sources(Application::class.java);

        }
    }
}
```

EventDAO (mentioned in the error) is just extending the BaseDAO and using the `datasource`

Comment: Why? If you are using Spring Boot why not just use the default way of creating a datasource? Not sure why you want to add your own>?

Comment: Because I can't seem to get that work as well :/ never done it but it's creating an `h2` datasource instead of using my properties

Comment: @M.Deinum edited the question, might be doing something wrong again there

Comment: It also looks like you are trying very hard to to use spring boot. Looks like you are creating new instances in the `EventsController` instead of using DI.

Comment: Why is your `BaseDAO` configuration AND a component? Also you shouldn't need anything regarding the datasource as spring boot should already create one based on the `applicatation.properties` and not `config.properties`.

Comment: Renamed my `config.properties` to `application.properties` (I had none), but it's still using a `h2` database (which i do have in my `src/test/resources` though). The `EventsController` calls a DAO which extends the BaseDAO (using `super.datasource`).

Comment: How can I use the Spring boot datasource? This is my first time trying this

Comment: You should not be calling `super.dataSource()`.... You should inject the `DataSource`, or better a `JdbcTemplate`. Those are all auto configured by Spring Boot. But as mentioned looks like you aren't using Spring Boot. You should have an application class with `@SpringBootApplication` which bootstraps your application. Then auto wire all the beans and don't create new instances. (But maybe Kotlin intercepts that but I doubt that).

Comment: @M.Deinum I do have a `Application.kt` with `@SpringBootApplication`, I'll edit the question and add it

Comment: Remove all datasource stuff from the dao. And just put an `@Autowired` field for `DataSource` in there. And don't create a new instance yourself (as, judging from the stack trace, you are doing).

Comment: Ok it's now returning `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: dataSource or dataSourceClassName or jdbcUrl is required.` (Still using the same application.properties file as mentioned in the question)

Comment: @M.Deinum edited the question to match current code

Comment: And are you auto wiring everything? Service, dao, controller etc.? You also have all needed dependencies? `spring-boot-starter-jdbc` and your jdbc driver is on the classpath.

Comment: No this is the first and only `@Autowire` I have ever written :S. I looked up some tutorials but they were all based around an `xml` file which I don't have

Comment: You shouldn't be using new in your code... You should auto wire everything.

Comment: All I want is to use the `jdbc.url`, `jdbc.username` and `jdbc.password` inside my BaseDAO class where it will look it up from the `application.properties` and will change the directory it's looking in when testing

Comment: Again.... You have to auto wire the beans... You shouldn't be creating new instances... You want to use Spring so you have to use the spring managed instances...

Comment: added `@Autowired` above all instances of classes instead of creating them. But now it just throws `kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property dao has not been initialized` that my DAO hasn't been initialized

Comment: Your dao should be annotated with `@Repository` and your service with `@Service`

Comment: Had to mark my classes as `open` to remove an error, but after doing that, I got the same error (`lateinit property dao has not been initialized`)

Comment: You should still let everything injected, also in your controller.

Comment: Everything is injected (well it isn't that's the problem) except domain classes and external Utils which only get used

Comment: and the `BaseDAO`'s constructor is called as a result of extending it

Answer (score 3):

The most common way we're doing it in our project is by constructor injection with `@Value` (works with Spring >= 4.3):

```
@PropertySource("classpath:config.properties")
@Component
open class BaseDAO(
        @Value("\${jdbc.url}") private val url: String,
        @Value("\${jdbc.username}") private val username: String,
        @Value("\${jdbc.password}") private val password: String
) {

    val config: HikariConfig = HikariConfig()

    init {
        Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver").newInstance()
        config.jdbcUrl = url
        config.username = username
        config.password = password
        config.minimumIdle = 2
        config.maximumPoolSize = 20
        config.idleTimeout = 60000
    }

}
```

I think you don't need this `companion object` to create a pool, just use a property inside your DAO.

Comment: I'm trying this now, the problem now is that I `extend` the `BaseDAO` on all my `DAO`'s. Using `class SomeDAO : BaseDAO() { }` returns `Multiple markers at this line - No value passed for parameter username - No value passed for parameter password - No value passed for parameter url`